# Angular 8 - TypeError: Class constructor EventEmitter cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, angular7, ionic4, angular8

I just updated my Ionic 4 app to from Angular 7 to Angular 8. However, when I run `ng serve`, it opens blank and I get this error in my browser console...

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Class constructor EventEmitter cannot be invoked without 'new'
    at new BackButtonEmitter (platform.js:29)
    at new Platform (platform.js:44)
    at _createClass (core.js:23184)
    at _createProviderInstance (core.js:23151)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:23098)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:24206)
    at resolveDep (core.js:24736)
    at createClass (core.js:24589)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.js:24400)
    at createViewNodes (core.js:35006)
```

Any idea what this is about?

Comment: It has been reported in [this issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15939), which is linked to [this other issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15979). A quick fix is given in [this comment](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15979#issuecomment-435057793).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by updating my entire package.json list...
https://flaviocopes.com/update-npm-dependencies/

Answer (score 1):

You must enter the code so users will know what you are doing,

I answer the question you ask, The same error tells you that you must do you must initialize the variable of type `EventEmitter` with `New` in this way

```
   @Output() variableEmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

I hope you will be of help mark as an answer to be useful to other users

Comment: The documents referenced in the error is the core part of angular which I never touched and should never. So I can't locate where this error is coming from.

Comment: Could it be that Ionic needs to update with Angular 8?

Comment: This problem is shown in those files but you should be making a reference to emitter that is not initialized

Comment: How are you implementing Emitter? can you show me the code

Comment: I fixed it by updating my entire package.json list.

Comment: Share your solution, so that it can be of help to other users